# Combining datasets in a single .npz file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I have four directories x_train, y_train, x_test, and y_test

each directory contains number of images. I want to convert them all to a single .npz file so that I can load them as shown below.

```
DATA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz'

path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('mnist.npz', DATA_URL)
with np.load(path) as data:
  train_examples = data['x_train']
  train_labels = data['y_train']
  test_examples = data['x_test']
  test_labels = data['y_test']
```

Don't worry about the URL I just want to create the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `savez()` method, see [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html).

```
import numpy as np
file_name = 'something.npz'
np.savez(file_name, x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train, x_test=x_test, y_test=y_test)
```